# Проблема при выводе кирилицы из ответа на requests запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests

Посредством requests делаю запрос на API. В ответе вижу, что вместо "Москва" отображается

> \xd0\x9c\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Как корректно отобразить кириллицу? Гуглил, пишут что в версии < 3 были такие проблемы, в актуальных версиях таких проблем нет.

Код:

```
import requests
import json

data = {
   'grant_type': 'password',
   'username': 'login',
   'password': 'pass',
   'client_id': 'id'
}

response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.16/api/oauth/token', data=data)
data = response.json()
jstr = data['access_token']
type = 'Bearer'
token = str(type) + ' ' + str(jstr)
print(f'Your token is {token}' ) 

headers = {
    'Authorization': token,
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
}

data = '[]'

response2 = requests.post('http://192.168.1.16/api/office/read-all', headers=headers, data=data)

print(headers) 
print(response2.content)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS использую Python 3.9

Comment: а что вернет response2.json()?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Заменил на response2.json вместо content. Теперь вывод корректный

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае, если

```
'Content-type': 'application/json'
```

ответ в json должен быть корректным, наче, можно проверить кодировку:

```
print(responce.encoding)
```

и, если там не utf-8, что-то cp1251, то декодировать:

```
responce.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Comment: А как же про `response2.json()`? :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне помог ответ от Jack_oS, заменил response2.content на response2.json()

Также если вам необходим экспорт респонса в файл, предлагаю сделать это следующим образом:

```
filename= 'test.json'
with open(filename, 'w', encoding) as f:
    json.dump(response.json(), f, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Без ensure_ascii = False будет вывод:

> \xd0\x9c\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0